# Getting wrong value while calculating max and min value Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am calculating max and min value from array of integer using JavaScript but as per my code the wrong value is coming. I am explaining my code below.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100];

const arr1 = arr.reduce((a,i) => {
  let max = a > i ? a:i;
  let min = a < i ? a:i;
  return {max: max, min: min};
},{})

console.log(arr1);
```

Here I am getting both max and min value as 100. Here I need to return max and min value from array.

Comment: you're comparing an object {} to your integer (always false), which does not meaningfully get the min max.  what you should have been doing is comparing your object's min property to i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with reduce this is the answer:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100];

const arr1 = arr.reduce((a,i) => {
  let max = a.max > i ? a.max:i;
  let min = a.min < i ? a.min:i;
  return {max, min};
},{})

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100];

var max = Math.max(...arr);

var min = Math.min(...arr);

console.log({max, min});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure `min` and `max`, check each with the actual value, adjust if necessary and return a new object with short hand properties.

As start object, you need some really large values.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100],
    minMax = array.reduce(({ min, max }, value) => {
        if (min > value) min = value;
        if (max < value) max = value;
        return { min, max };
    }, { min: Infinity, max: -Infinity });

console.log(minMax);
```